getting a specific field from every document in a collection
I am using Dart Flutter and Firebase Firestore.
I have a collection order with auto-ID'd documents containing a name and price.
I want to set a double total to a sum of every price in the collection 'order'.
I have set up a query snapshot, forEach function, and docs.get()     method.
I have tried to set up as a map, and consulted chatGPT. The total isn't either updating or getting the price of each doc.
I have used an initState() { calculateTotal(); }  to call the function.
  double total = 0;

  Future<void> calculateTotal() async {
    total = 0;

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('order').get();

    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      total += doc.get('price');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    initState() {
      calculateTotal();
    }



You aren't showing any code that updates the documents that were read.  All you're doing is computing a variable in memory called total, which doesn't change anything in any document.

QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot =
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('order').get();

querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
 total += double.tryParse(doc['price']??"0")??0;
});

you can try this code snipped

Thank you, this code worked.
I also had issues with setting the variable state to actually show in the app,
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
calculateTotal().then((_) {
setState(() {});
});
}
issue has been resolved now.
